# Linq query for complicated model

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I can't seem to find out the query for a complicated model I'm using. The model looks like this:

```
public class Stash
    {
        public int StashId { get; set; }

        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }

        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

A product can have several locations and now I want to get all the locations that are connected to a product.

Comment: What's your input? List of Stash?

Comment: @CuongLe Indeed, a List of Stash

Answer (score 0):

```
var stashes = new List<Stash>();
int productID = [your id];
var result = stashes.Where(stash => stash.ProductId == productID).Select(stash => stash.Location);
```

If you need the result to be a `List` add `.ToList()` at the end.

Comment: The query should work. You are sure there are matching elements in your list of stashes that have the correct ID?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure! I think the Select part is not working, since I can the items by only using the productId, but really need to location too.

Comment: Interesting. Would you [join me in the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143873/query-debug) to work on this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> Include to load reference of other entity

```
var result=context.entity.Include(c=>c.product)
 .where(c=>c.product.productId==productid)
```